# ActivityNotFoundException in Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-manifest, intentservice

I'm developing push notifications in my android app. At this point:

```
if (checkPlayServices()){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The device must be registered to get the token and send it to the server, but when I try start the Activity the code crashes. Here is the error shown in the logcat:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cgp.tpvtablet/com.cgp.tpvtablet.activity.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.cgp.tpvtablet/com.cgp.tpvtablet.area_push.notification.RegistrationIntentService}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

In the manifest the RegistrationIntentService is declared as a service in its current package:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.cgp.tpvtablet"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".area_push.notification.MyGCMListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".area_push.notification.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".area_push.notification.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false"/>
</application>
```

The editor suggest me this path when I write RegistrationIntentService in the manifest.
Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `RegistrationIntentService` is a service why are you using `startActivity(intent);`

since its not an activity it wont work and will crash

you need `startService`

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest, the main activity has a relative path ".activity.MainActivity", what is the base path you put in manifest package attribute?

Comment: The package is: com.nvp.testapp